# Hystrix command requiring cleanup when timed-out

Tags: hystrix

I have an Hystrix command that requires cleanup when timed-out.
Our current approach to handle this is as follows:

```
public class MyCommand extends HystrixCommand<MyResponse> {

    @Override
    public MyResponse run() {
        // do stuff

        // Cleanup if timed out
        if( this.isResponseTimedOut() ) {
           // perform cleanup
        }

        return myresponse;
    }
}
```

Does the Hystrix framework provide another way for that?

Comment: Anybody with advices?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't determine reliably inside the `run()` method if a timeout has occured: The `run()` method is running in a separated thread while the caller is waiting. While you are checking in the `run()` method if a timeout has occured, the calling thread might time out and you will not know about it. The code you suggest will work most of the time, but there is a small time window on each call where it will not work.

A save place to check if a timeout has occured would be the `fallback()` method. Please note that the original "do stuff" as described in your method might still be running at this point: Hystrix will send the original `run()` method a `java.lang.Thread.interrupt()`. Depending on your "do stuff" the results may vary.

I hope this is an answer to your question. If you could give more information in your question, I can update my answer to include it.